# What's the easiest way to make consistent simple walls?

Tags: modeling

Blender beginner here. I imported an image of a floor plan into Blender, aligned it with the grid, scaled it so one unit = 1 foot (it's from the 60s so Imperial). But I'm having issues making the walls:

First I tried putting a loop cut in my first wall and extruding it, but I don't know how to make a cut that's exactly the same width as the existing wall.

So then I tried copying and pasting the first wall instead, rotating it 90 degrees, and snapping it to the first wall. But it doesn't want to snap even though I turned on snap.

Is there a better way to go about this process?

[image]

Comment: There aren't any ways to do it faster.

Comment: Ok, if I go with extruding then, how do I specify the exact with of the cut please?

Comment: Press e and set the axis (By pressing X,Y,Z) and type in the amount.

Comment: To rotate click off and press r and do the same thing.

Comment: Hello :). You can do it pretty fast using a simple a bezier curve. No messy loopcuts and you can adjust the wall size any time. I can post a full answer if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks Jachym! Adding Bezier curve to my google search found something that seems to explain what you say: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHI6JXxC_hs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umhs1dTPP6o

Make one wall the exact width and height you want.
In edit mode, extrude the end face of the wall exactly the width of the wall: e, enter number that is width of the wall.
Then extrude the adjacent face 90 degrees to that and continue. Easy.

Answer (score 2):

**Solidify modifier.**

*For recent builds (2.82) with the complex mode*

[image]

Consider using the solidify modifier. Model your walls as simple edges on the plan.. When done extrude to wall height to. Add a solidify modifier to give walls thickness.

Fiddle with settings, for example making offset negative half thickness will keep original edge mid wall.

Comment: That is only in 2.82 experimental daily builds.

Comment: Not really. Solidify produces non-manifold geometry if it gets non-manifold geometry in the current 2.81 version while it's improved in the experimental builds.