# Blender solidify thinner along axis

Tags: modifiers, axis

I'm working on an object that is essentially a section of a sphere, and I need to have the object have a wall thickness that gets thinner along the X-axis (from left to right). At he left side (A) I need the wall thickness to be 0.7, and I need it to be half that (0.35) at the right side (B). I don't want any variation across the Z or Y axis.

The solidify tool is working great to add thickness, but I need it to be a variable thickness based on the X axis distance, so that it smoothly drops from 0.7-0.35. Any help would be much appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Solidify modifier like many others, can be assigned to a Vertex Group. In the case of Solidify, the vertex weights affect thickness. If you paint a linear gradient down the right axis:

[image]

Then there's quite a lot of tweaking-room left in the Solidify's 'Thickness' and 'Factor' settings .. maybe enough to get the precision you need?

[image]

Comment: Been given a [little more love in 2.82](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161007/15543)

Comment: @batFINGER   Ahh ! Very Nice! Looks like quite an important update.. not just for arch. but for offsets in modelling in general.

Comment: Looking very _Churchillian (sans cigar)_ in the bow tie, Mr Betts.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much.  Ultimately I was looking for a dropdown/slider style solution but the gradient sketching worked really well with some tweaking.

Comment: @batFINGER (_raising two fingers_).. Happy Christmas, Mr. FINGER!